# How to get data from two tables and save it in DTO in Net Core Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I just explain this in example, say I have two tables, field and modulefield

```
field
id     name          ismodule
1      Firstname     1
2      Lastname      0

modulefield
id     moduleid      fieldid
1      22            1
```

That is a simple representation of my database. Now in EF, how can I get a row with these columns

```
modulefield.moduleid     field.id     field.name
22                       1            Firstname
```

Basically, I just want to get the modulefield.moduleid if the field.ismodule is true.

The equivalent sql script I think for this is

```
SELECT b.submoduleid, a.* FROM field a, modulefield b;
```

My current code is this(snippet)

```
   var result = new List<FieldDTO>();
   var fields = await _repo.GetAsync<Field>();
   result = _mapper.Map<List<FieldDTO>>(fields);
```

Comment: What is the relation between field and modulefield? Are there many modules per field or just one can exist?

Comment: modules can have multiple fields. But field can only be bound to 1 module. Module is another table by the way. And modulefields is like their bridge.

Comment: Using modulefields "like a bridge" suggests many-to-many relationship.
To use one-to-many relationship, you don't need that bridge. I'll write an example later today..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [linq join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join) to return a `List<FieldDTO>` directly.

```
var result = (from e in _context.Fields
                     join mf in _context.ModuleFields on e.Id equals mf.FieldId
                     where e.IsModule == 1

                     select new FieldDTO
                     {
                         ModulefieldModuleid = mf.ModuleId,
                         FieldId = e.Id,
                         FieldName=e.Name


                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there could be more then one Module per Field.
Query:

```
SELECT mf.submoduleid, f.id, f.name 
FROM field AS f, modulefield AS mf
WHERE f.ismodule = 1 AND
    f.id = mf.fieldid
```

EF Linq expression:

```
List<FieldDTO> result = _context.Fields
    .Include("ModuleField")
    .Where(f => f.ismodule == true)
    .Select(f => new FieldDTO(){
        ModuleFieldModuleId = f.ModuleField.moduleid,
        FieldId = f.id,
        FieldName = f.Name})
    .ToList();
```

ModuleField is navigation property in Field class.

**EDIT:**
Models:

```
public class Field
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsModule 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Module != null;
        }
    }

    public virtual Module Module {get; set;}
}

public class Module
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get; set }
}
```

On model creating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Field>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Module); // Marking property optional
```

Getting the Module.ModuleId if IsModule of Field is true:

```
List<FieldDTO> result = _context.Fields
    .Include("Module")
    .Where(f => f.IsModule == true)
    .Select(f => new FieldDTO(){
        ModuleFieldModuleId = f.Module.Id,
        FieldId = f.Id,
        FieldName = f.Name})
    .ToList();
```